# 0 Call to a member function purgePrivate() on null

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, fatal-error, php7

I just tried to login and I got this error message that I've never seen before.

0 Call to a member function purgePrivate() on null

I'm not sure what would have caused it.

It's PHP 7.3.

Interestingly I was on PHP7.4 but the redirect system didn't work so only my homepage showed.

Comment: Can you offer more context regarding this method which does not have its expected object? Any additional/relevant debugging details will be beneficial.

Comment: What sort of information would be useful Mick?  It's started happening commonly on one of my sites.  Already you have helped me, I could do a search for purgePrivate and see where it is in my code.  I'll try that then if it's a component I can report it.

Comment: Found it thanks to your hint.  Much appreciated @mickmackusa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Litespeed Cache.  It is somehow related to the Joomla Login.  You can test this is true by uninstalling the Litespeed Cache plugin.

I went into cPanel and I went to Terminal and I did a search by copying and pasting this (right click to paste)

`grep -Ri purgeprivate public_html`

and it found:

> $this->plugin->lscInstance->purgePrivate("com_virtuemart.cart");

Problem found.  Solution awaiting.  Raised on GitHub here:

https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache-joomla/issues/42

Answer (score 1):

Open lscache.php file
it's in the folder httpdocs/plugins/system/lscache
Comment on this Line 549

```
public function onUserAfterLogin($options) {
    if (!$this->cacheEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->app->isAdmin()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->lscInstance->checkPrivateCookie();
    $this->checkVary();
    if ($this->esiEnabled) {
        $this->lscInstance->purgeAllPrivate();
        $this->log();
    }
}

public function onUserAfterLogout($options) {
    if (!$this->cacheEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->app->isAdmin()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->checkVary();
    if ($this->esiEnabled) {
        $this->lscInstance->purgeAllPrivate();
        $this->log();
    }
}

public function onUserLoginFailure($respond) {
    $this->lscInstance->purgePrivate('joomla.login');
    $this->log();
}
```

Then try to login
After that, uninstall LiteSpeed Cache Plugin.

Comment: But uninstalling isn't fixing the problem; it is making the problem go away.  What if you actually want the plugin and just need it to work properly?

Comment: Thanks for posting @Devi Renada, welcome to the community, we need helpful people like you.  Do you know what this functionality actually does?  What would I be losing by commenting this?  It's an Open Source project, hopefully we can submit the code on Github to fix it for everyone.  https://github.com/litespeedtech/lscache-joomla